# Keep placeholder when focused in webkit browser using css

Tags: css, webkit

I currently have a browser, unknown, that will clear the `placeholder` text when a text field is focused. How can I, using CSS, keep the text in place until the user types or is this impossible?

My thought is this. The placeholder isn't removed but merely hidden using CSS, or whatever, and can therefore be manipulated to show even though the default is not to. My hope is that at least webkit should have such a feature (there is no need for it to work in any other browsers that webkit based).

The following code would change the default color of the placeholder:

```
[placeholder]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #888888;
}
```

Any answers and/or thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking for? Maybe it's just me, but I'm very confused.

Comment: I want to have my placeholder, on a input field, visible once focused. This is not the default behaviour. The "fix" only concern webkit families and all other browsers are in this thread irrelevant. I would like, using CSS, to keep the placeholder until the user start typing...

Comment: Isn't that the normal behavior? Every `placeholder` attribute does that.

Comment: The default behaviour for the PyGTK webkit browser is to remove it on focus.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to not use JavaScript to implement this conveniently?

Comment: I just thought there should be a way to do it, given that webkit usually offers much more than people actually can use (due to other browsers not having similar support) and therefore I would like to use CSS. There are many workarounds with Javascript and JQuery I know, just wanted to see if this is possible.

Comment: I just re-read the webkit documentation on the topic of the `placeholder` attribute; and as far as I can tell, there is no extra feature as you described other than it's normal behavior. Sorry, but honestly I doubt you will find a vanilla solution to your problem in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, only for webkit, add a `-webkit-transition-duration` property for an infinite time to delay the placeholder from going away. You will however have to change the value to `0s` using Javascript when the user start to type unless you want the text and the placeholder overlapping.

Example:

```
[placeholder]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #888888;
    -webkit-transition-duration:86400s; // 24 hours
}
```